# How to pass current time to recurring Hangfire job?

Tags: hangfire

I have a recurring Hangfire job that runs daily. As part of the logic the job fetches entities created within the last 24 hours. It uses DateTime.Now in the logic. I realize that this is not a robust design in the case that the job fails and it is run several days later. Is there any way I can pass the current time as a parameter to a recurring job? Or do I need to rewrite the logic to be independent of the current time? I have tried `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => FooAction.Execute(GetTime()), cronSchedule);` but as expected that just always passses the time that the recurring job was created.

One idea would be to skip the recurring job and create a regular Hangfire job instead. The last thing the job should do is create a new job and pass the specified time as parameter. But I would prefer to use a recurring job if I can.

Comment: You could have a recurring job run that is responsible for creating non-recurring jobs, and passing the current time into those.

Comment: @mason Good idea. I will do that.

Comment: @mason You should write that as an answer..., pretty slick and simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You could have a recurring job run that is responsible for creating non-recurring jobs, and passing the current time into those."
From comment by @mason.